# Error in send e-mail function

Tags: java, maven, compiler-errors

Try to email in Java with Swing, but i get error which i didn't found how to fix, there is code (which i got from somewhere.. and removed a few Fields):

```
 import sun.plugin2.message.transport.Transport;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Properties;

class SendEmailClient extends JFrame {
   ....    
    private SendEmailClient() {
        InitializeUI();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                SendEmailClient client = new SendEmailClient();
                client.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private void InitializeUI() {
        setTitle("Send E-mail Client");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(new Dimension(400, 280));

        // Header Panel
      }

    private class SendEmailActionListener implements ActionListener {
        SendEmailActionListener() {
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", mailSmtpHostComboBox.getSelectedItem());
            props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");

            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
            try {
                InternetAddress fromAddress = new InternetAddress(fromField.getText());
                InternetAddress toAddress = new InternetAddress(toField.getText());

                javax.mail.Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                message.setFrom(fromAddress);
                message.setRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress);
                message.setSubject(subjectField.getText());
                message.setText(contentTextArea.getText());

                Transport.send(message, usernameField.getText(),
                        new String(passwordField.getPassword()));
            } catch (MessagingException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and maven dependencies (may be some of them isn't needed):

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jdesktop.bsaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>bsaf</artifactId>
    <version>1.9RC5</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And on the Send function there is error:

```
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method send(javax.mail.Message,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
  location: interface sun.plugin2.message.transport.Transport
```

I am trying to add some dependencies in pom, but it seems to be wrong decison, but don't mind how can fix it.. Does someone know?

Comment: Swing has nothing to do with sending email. So first get your code working by hard coding data for the email properties. Then once this is working you make the code more dynamic by using Swing to get user input for the message and email address.

Answer (score 0):

First of all import **Transport** class from correct pacakge.

```
   import javax.mail.Transport;//Use this
```

Now use the **Authenticator** to authenticate the username and password

```
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
      new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
      });
```

Now call the **send()** method of the **Transport** class and pass the **Message** object.

```
    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("from-email@gmail.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
            InternetAddress.parse("to-email@gmail.com"));
        message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
        message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler,"
            + "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```